# _mm256_setr_epi64x causing wrong results on x86 msvc v143 build with /arch:AVX

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, simd, avx

EDIT2: I have additionally reduced the case and improved the [testing code](https://github.com/Epixu/msvc_but_repro/blob/main/Main.cpp)

I have been pondering this for a week now, it is probably a compiler bug, but I can't be completely sure.

I'm using MSVC - 19.37.32822.0 with cmake, my `target_compile_options` are `/arch:AVX` (`/arch:AVX2` fails, too).
My `target_compile_features` is `cxx_std_20`.

The `_mm256_setr_epi64x` and `_mm256_set_epi64x` intrinsics produce wrong results. The problem doesn’t reproduce in debug builds.
The problem doesn’t reproduce for g++, clang++, clang-cl builds with all combinations of SIMD options.

It occurs only on this particular x86 msvc build with `/arch:AVX` or `/arch:AVX2` enabled. <strike>**Building with /O1 and /O2 fixes the problem, and since this happens only in Release, that's a completely viable solution!**</strike> No, it doesn't fix it.

I haven’t tried any previous msvc toolsets - only the latest v143 (MSVC - 19.37.32822.0)

**EDIT:**
It appears, that this problem is harder to reproduce than anticipated - [godbolt doesn't allow me to run it with msvc compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/Exzr5jW7x). At first glance, it seems to be connected with Catch2 testing framework. I've setup a github [repo](https://github.com/Epixu/msvc_but_repro) with the required cross-platform cmake setup to reproduce it consistently. It will automatically fetch Catch2 testing framework for you. Once you clone, just open the CMakeLists.txt with visual studio 2022, and it should work out-of-the-box.

Here's an excerpt from the [reproduction test](https://github.com/Epixu/msvc_but_repro/blob/main/Main.cpp):

```cpp
/// FAILS                                                               
TEST_CASE("Testing with GIVEN", "[bug]") {
   const int64_t values[4] {11, 22, 33, 0};

   GIVEN("a1") {
      const __m256i a1 = _mm256_setr_epi64x(
         values[0],
         values[1],
         values[2],
         0 // if i substitute this with values[3] it works fine
      );

      WHEN("a1 is stored") {
         alignas(32) int64_t b1[4];
         _mm256_store_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(b1), a1);

         THEN("The result should be correct") {
            REQUIRE(b1[0] == values[0]);
            REQUIRE(b1[1] == values[1]);
            REQUIRE(b1[2] == values[2]); // always fails here
            REQUIRE(b1[3] == values[3]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You can clone it and experiment with it. I've also added a workflow (if you click on [actions](https://github.com/Epixu/msvc_but_repro/actions/runs/6338982664) and if you're logged in github, you can even see the build/test logs)

I've written the [corresponding bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/_mm256_setr_epi64x-causing-wrong-results/10479174?) on the microsoft website, but I decided it could be useful to get some information from here, too.

Comment: Your asm listing appears incomplete.  `vinsertf128 ymm0,ymm0,xmm1,1` copies XMM1 to the high half of YMM0, but you don't show the instruction that loaded something into XMM1.  Unless that's the bug, and MSVC forgot to do that, and is using stale garbage from a register instead of `values[2] = 33`?  Is this a debug build or something? In an optimized build we'd expect constant-propagation.

Comment: Anyway, your C++ source with intrinsics look fine to me, I don't see any bugs, so it looks like a compiler bug.  I'm not familiar with these `GIVEN("a1")` and `WHEN`  macros(?) from your test framework, and it's not a [mcve] that could be compiled on its own (e.g. copy/pasted into a stand-alone `.cpp` like on https://godbolt.org/ to look at the asm))

Comment: Oh, you did say this is a release build, but it's still using EBP as a frame pointer because there are some over-aligned local vars (like the `alignas(32)` array), so it needs to align ESP and be able to restore it later.  I guess MSVC just really doesn't like to optimize away intrinsics!  Or that's tied up in whatever bug is affecting it.

Comment: Have you tested with x64 MSVC?  Intrinsics for 64-bit integers in 32-bit mode might be a special case.  (Not that you're doing anything wrong: some compilers don't provide some int64 intrinsics in 32-bit mode, especially single-instruction intrinsics like for `pinsrq` or `movq r64, xmm` which don't exist in 32-bit mode. Any they do provide should work, like they do in other compilers!)

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, if you follow the link to my CI you'll see that i've checked practically everything. PS: I've improved my minimal repro and shared a godbolt link

Comment: I haven't tried building it with /O2, i'll check tomorrow to see if behavior changes

Comment: With optimization enabled (https://godbolt.org/z/Kh77xqsE6), it does still load and store a vector (not optimizing away the intrinsics and compiling to return a constant 0 like gcc/clang do).  But it did constprop through the `set` intrinsic so it's just loading a 32-byte constant from memory, which it defines with `db 11, 0,0,0,0,... 22, 0,0,..., '!', 0,0,0, ...` (except it uses hex like `0bH`.  Except for `33` where it uses `'!'` because it's printable ASCII, unlike the other numbers I guess. Hilarious.)  I didn't count the zeros, but the constant looks right, and so do the compares.

Comment: The asm from MSVC19.37 in your Godbolt link does *not* reproduce the problem.  It's hilariously inefficient, e.g. using an `imul` by `0` to get an index for the low element of `_mm256_setr_epi64x`, so I wasn't sure I was following everything.  So I copy/pasted the asm to a local `.asm` file,  tweaked a few things to get it to build with NASM's `%use masm` compat macro package (`=` to `equ`, and removing `YMMWORD PTR`, and removed the security cookie function calls). Then I linked it into a 32-bit Linux executable so I could run it.  It returns `0`. So the test framework stuff must be relevant.

Comment: @PeterCordes you are absolutely correct! I made a playground for investigating the bug in github: https://github.com/Epixu/msvc_but_repro
You can clone it and experiment with it. I've also added a workflow (if you click on actions and if you're logged in github, you can even see the build/test logs)
It requires cmake, and will automatically fetch Catch2 testing framework, which seems to be required for the repro

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/vv8Kq4Eh8 has a build with `#include <catch.hpp>`; the library is available in the dropdown.  I haven't tried it yet, but the 2x `vpunpcklqdq` / `vinsertf128` that implements `_mm256_setr_epi64x` looks about the same as before.  Maybe there's something else going on, or something I didn't notice.  I don't have Windows or MSVC installed locally, but your github reproducer should hopefully help someone else repro it themselves, including actual MSVC developers which is of course the most important audience.

Comment: I think it is worthy to mention, that `TEST_CASE("Testing without GIVEN, multiple loops", "[bug]")` works fine, if we remove the loop, so it probably has to do with register junk or something?

Comment: I right clicked and did "reveal linked code" on the setr in the `// FAILS` case.  I don't see it reading a reg it didn't write.  The bug you're seeing is either more subtle than that, or isn't reproduced in the build on Godbolt.  Disassembly from a local build that you've verified fails would be more definitive (and more worth spending time looking at; I didn't spend a huge amount of time looking at this myself since you've already reported it upstream, identifying the bug in the asm myself isn't going to help them find it or fix it faster.  If there is one, they'll be able to see it easily.)

Comment: Almost certainly a compiler bug that MS should fix, but yes posting an answer would be a good place to record the build options where the bug does / doesn't happen (at least for your test case.)  I'm also somewhat curious what incorrect asm it ends up making, so if you have disassembly from the failing test-case, that could be possibly interesting.  But there's not really any way for people who aren't MSVC developers to do anything with that information, except maybe have some kind of guess about what other situations might manifest the same bug.

Comment: No, actually that doesn't fix it...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Building with `/O1` and `/O2` flags fixes the problem, as demonstrated in [the repository](https://github.com/Epixu/msvc_but_repro), and since this happens only in Release, that's a completely viable solution!
I'm still curious as to why it happens, though. It might be a sign of a deeper problem.</strike>

Comment: Did you mean `/Od`? There's no `/O0`

Comment: No, i extrapolated wrongly, that there's such an option, as the compiler didn't complain about it. But it seems that /O doesn't actually fix the problem